# Select post that has three terms at the same time

Tags: wordpress, filter

In wordpress, how can I get the post id's that are asigned to three categories at the same time?

Example:

```
object_id      term_taxonomy_id
-------------------------------
   6913            65
   7000            80
   7500            65
   2500            20
   6913            67
   6913            70
   5555            65
   5555            67
   6913            66
```

So the post that has terms 65, 67 and 70 at the same time is 6913.

Answer (score 0):

Using a query you can get the post having these three categories

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` p
LEFT JOIN `wp_term_relationships` tr ON (p.ID = tr.object_id)
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON (tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id )
WHERE p.post_status='published' AND tt.term_id IN( 65,67,70)
HAVING COUNT(tr.object_id) =3
```

Above query will return all the posts that have these 3 categories 65,67,70

You can use wordpress `wpdb` class to run your queries

```
global $wpdb;
$posts=$wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` p
    LEFT JOIN `wp_term_relationships` tr ON (p.ID = tr.object_id)
    INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON (tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id )
    WHERE p.post_status='published' AND tt.term_id IN( 65,67,70)
    HAVING COUNT(tr.object_id) =3");
```